# How to remove the viewstate of a Control programmatically?

Tags: viewstate, radgrid

I have a control, RadGrid, for which viewstate should stay enabled.

Only when a condition is met, a button is clicked, the viewstate of that control should be removed so that the new values are bound to this control.

How to remove the viewstate of a Control programmatically?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can remove an item from ViewState with:

```
ViewState["controlName"] = null;
```

However, after this, you will need to recreate the control and re-add it to the page, else your ViewState will not match your control tree.

Comment: ViewState.Count is always 0 when Page_Init and Page_Load.